# Where can I get the Microsoft.SqlServer.Mso.dll & Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, dll

I can't seem to find these anywhere, I want to do some SMO stuff.

I am using VS 2010 Ultimate and SQL Express 2008; thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get them here:

[Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Feature Pack, August 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c6c3e9ef-ba29-4a43-8d69-a2bed18fe73c&displaylang=en)

Scroll down to the section called **"Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Management Objects"**

For x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=123708&clcid=0x409
For x64: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=123709&clcid=0x409